# How to open document in Microsoft Office via reverse proxy?

Tags: sharepoint-server, office, office-integration, adfs, reverse-proxy

We have a reverse proxy that does SAML authentication and then translates it to kerberos delegation to our SharePoint Server Subscription Edition web app with Windows Integrated authentication. This works fine for browsing the web interface.

But how do we open files in Word for example? Right now, Word will open the URL to the file, but display the login page from ADFS instead of the document content. It is not a login prompt, it just opens the login page's HTML in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open Office documents through a reverse proxy, the proxy needs to support the Microsoft Office client protocol (MS-OCPROTO). In our case, we were using KEMP as proxy, which does not support this. AD FS Web Application Proxy (WAP) supports this however. So if your current proxy does not support this, you could passthrough the traffic to a WAP server.